# Devise update resource without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I've looked for a way to do this, and I found 
`resource.update_without_password` if the goal is to just update some user attributes.  But I'm trying to update subscription information (like credit card details) that will be sent off to [Chargify](https://www.chargify.com/).

How do I do this?

Relevant code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
  def update
    super
    if params[:product]
        if resource.create_and_subscribe(params[:product])
            if resource.active_for_authentication?
                set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?

                subscription = resource.subscription
                if subscription
                    SubscriptionMailer.signup_success(subscription).deliver
                end
            else
                set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
                expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
                respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def create_and_subscribe(product_handle)
    if subscription_status != :active
      return unless self.valid?
      product = Chargify::Product.find_by_handle(product_handle)
      if product.nil?
        errors.add(:base, "Product must be selected")
        return nil
      end

      User.transaction do
        self.save
        subscription =
            subscription_service.
                  subscribe(self, subscription_params(product.id))

        if subscription.errors.any?
          subscription.errors.full_messages.each{|err| errors.add(:base, err)}
          false
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        else
          self.subscription_status = subscription.state
          self.product = subscription.product.handle
          self.save(validate: false)
          true
        end
      end
    else
      errors.add(:base, "You already have a subscription")
    end
  end
end
```

,

```
class ChargifySubscriptionService

def subscribe(user, params)
  record = ChargifyRecord.new
  record.user_id = user.id
  subscription = Chargify::Subscription.new(params)
  record.request_params = params
  record.created_at = Time.now
  record.status = subscription.save ? :success : :failure
  record.responded_at = Time.now
  record.response = subscription.to_json
  record.save
  subscription
end
```

Comment: could you isolate the code of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have my user model set up to update user with out password

```
#app/models/user.rb

  attr_accessor :updating_password
  def should_validate_password?
      updating_password || new_record?
  end
```

Now in my controller I do check if the password was submitted or not

```
#app/controllers/users/users_controller.rb
  before_filter :check_password_submitted, :only => :update
  def check_password_submitted
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
      user.updating_password = false
    else
      user.updating_password = true
    end
  end
```

I hope that this helps
and Happy Coding